# Elastic search all my indexes show red. What could be the reason and how to solve this?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two nodes of ed Node1 Node2 on seperate ec2 instances. Node2 shows this response and Node1 is inaccessible. Can it be because of problem with Node2. Also how to make instances healthy again?

[image: http://server-ipstrong text:9200/_cat/indices/?v]

Answer (score 0):

A cluster will turn yellow if there is at least one yellow node in the cluster.
Same for red cluster state which indicate at least one red node in the cluster.

A node will be yellow if there is at least one yellow index.
Nodes will turn red if there is a primary shard missing on this node.

Yellow indices indicate missing replica shards - you are probably not fault-tolerant any more. This happens when you lose a node containing replica shards or increase the replica count for an index afterward.
Solutions:

- reduce the number of replicas if not necessary (will reduce fault tolerance and search speed)
- add new nodes if you lost one or more, the cluster will reallocate the replicas if all criteria are met by the new nodes

Red indices indicate missing primary shards - you are about to lost data. This happens if you lose a not replicated primary shard by node failure.

- restore the lost nodes containing the missing primary shards
- reindex the data form origin source or restore your snapshot

In order to regain a green cluster, fix all red and/or yellow indices on all nodes.